# Destructuring, variable creation and code optimlisation in Julia

Tags: optimization, julia, tuples, destructuring

This is more a question on how the Julia language is working rather than a technical issue. I have discovered structure and tuple destructuring but I am wondering what are the underlying processes regarding memory allocation.

I am currently writing a code to run simulations involving ODE solving. I store all my parameters in a tuple, which is used as an argument for the ODE function `ODE_fun`. I have red that destructuring tuples is a nice way to use a subset of the elements of a tuple and prevents you from writing: `tuple.a` each time you refer to parameter `a` for instance. But is it creating a new variable each time or? If yes, it looks less optimal than calling `tuple.a` because it would create a new `a` variable at each iteration of the ODE solving algorithm. This may be significant with tuples containing dozen of parameters and vectors. Or is it creating a kind of pointer pointing to `tuple.a`? Is there a way to use destructuring in an optimal way? Unfortunately, documentations are quite unclear...

Comment: What is the type of `tuple.a`? If it is a native type like a fixed-size <=64 bit integers (or similar like native floating-point types), then creating a temporary variable is free in term of performance. The only cost comes from the extraction of the attribute itself in memory. An optimized de-structuring should be theoretically equally fast but I am not sure this is as efficient in practice though. I expect the two to be close and `tuple.a` to be potentially slightly faster due to possible missed optimizations (or runtime checks).

Comment: Yes my variables are either Int64 or Float64. Is it also free in term of performance if tuple.a is a vector of Int64 or Float64? For me, copying vectors is something that should be avoided.

Comment: This has zero cost, you are just creating a new name referring to an existing object. No new object or value is created. `a = tuple.a` just means "From now on I will use the name `a` to refer to the value that `tuple.a` refers to". It doesn't make any difference if it's a primitive type, a user type or a huge heap-allocated object.

Comment: Ok perfect, that was exactly the information I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: AFAIK If you want to perform a copy, then you need to explicitly do that in Julia (like in Python, except for immutable types which include native types).

Comment: Slicing into an array will also make a copy.

Answer (score 1):

If the type of the `NamedTuple` `argument` is known at the compile time, it does not matter whether you do `myfun(argument.a, argument.b)` or `myfun(argument...)`

#### Explanation

Since the tuple has a fixed type the Julia's compiler can handle that (providing that the type is not ambiguous).

Consider this two functions and a `NamedTuple` `mypars`:

```
function f(pars)
    +(pars...)
end
function f2(pars)
    +(pars.a, pars.b)
end

mypars = (;a=1, b=4)
```

It can be clearly seen that both are non allocating:

```
julia> @btime f($mypars)
  1.400 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime f2($mypars)
  1.400 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Let is now look into the compilation process. The lowered codes are obviously different

```
julia> @code_lowered f(mypars)
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = Core._apply_iterate(Base.iterate, Main.:+, pars)
└──      return %1
)

julia> @code_lowered f2(mypars)
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = Base.getproperty(pars, :a)
│   %2 = Base.getproperty(pars, :b)
│   %3 = %1 + %2
└──      return %3
)
```

However, when inferring type compiler realizes these are basically the same:

```
julia> @code_typed f(mypars)
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = Core.getfield(pars, 1)::Int64
│   %2 = Core.getfield(pars, 2)::Int64
│   %3 = Base.add_int(%1, %2)::Int64
└──      return %3
) => Int64

julia> @code_typed f2(mypars)
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = Base.getfield(pars, :a)::Int64
│   %2 = Base.getfield(pars, :b)::Int64
│   %3 = Base.add_int(%1, %2)::Int64
└──      return %3
) => Int64
```

This in turn means that LLVM will get identical code to compile:

```
julia> @code_llvm f(mypars)
;  @ REPL[1]:1 within `f`
; Function Attrs: uwtable
define i64 @julia_f_702([2 x i64]* nocapture noundef nonnull readonly align 8 dereferenceable(16) %0) #0 {
top:
;  @ REPL[1]:2 within `f`
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds [2 x i64], [2 x i64]* %0, i64 0, i64 0
  %2 = getelementptr inbounds [2 x i64], [2 x i64]* %0, i64 0, i64 1
; ┌ @ int.jl:87 within `+`
   %unbox = load i64, i64* %1, align 8
   %unbox1 = load i64, i64* %2, align 8
   %3 = add i64 %unbox1, %unbox
; └
  ret i64 %3
}

julia> @code_llvm f2(mypars)
;  @ REPL[2]:1 within `f2`
; Function Attrs: uwtable
define i64 @julia_f2_704([2 x i64]* nocapture noundef nonnull readonly align 8 dereferenceable(16) %0) #0 {
top:
;  @ REPL[2]:2 within `f2`
; ┌ @ Base.jl:37 within `getproperty`
   %1 = getelementptr inbounds [2 x i64], [2 x i64]* %0, i64 0, i64 0
   %2 = getelementptr inbounds [2 x i64], [2 x i64]* %0, i64 0, i64 1
; └
; ┌ @ int.jl:87 within `+`
   %unbox = load i64, i64* %1, align 8
   %unbox1 = load i64, i64* %2, align 8
   %3 = add i64 %unbox1, %unbox
; └
  ret i64 %3
}
```

You  can run `@code_native f(mypars)` and `@code_native f2(mypars)` to find out that the resulting binaries are identical.